# Покрыть тестами Service

Tags: android, android-service, android-testing

**Дано:**

Активити в которой запускается AlarmManager.

AlarmManager запускет раз в n минут Service.

Service с помощью Retrofit 2 & SimpleXmlConverter скачивает объект с сервера и передает его методу для парсинга.

Метод парсит объект и в зависимости от того, что пришло - запускает активити и передает в интенте текст, который нужно показать в алерте.

**Вопрос:**

Как и с помощью чего покрыть тестами работу этого сервиса ?

Answer (score 1):

Грубо говоря вам нужно проверить те ли методы вызываются. То есть вы говорите, что закончилось скачивание и должен вызваться метод парсинга, а тест вам отвечает вызвался этот метод или нет. И так далее. 
Вот хороший пример как это реализовать [https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-testing/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#5 ]